# Broadcasting Event - Works Good on Server-Side, but Not on Client-Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, laravel, socket.io

I am using Laravel 5.1. I am trying to fire a UserAddedFriend event called on related function and get caught by Socket.io and Redis.

So I run `node socket.js` on the serverside. Everything seems okay to me, and when I open 2 browsers and login with 2 different users (X and Y), both gets connected.

When I call the function *'addFriend'* function, event gets fired. On the server, `node socket.js` prints `Received` text as well; however nothing gets returned on any of the browsers in console.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

---

So on 'addFriend()' function, I fire this event:

```
 \Event::fire(new UserAddedFriend($username));
```

On class **UserAddedFriend**:

```
class UserAddedFriend extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast

public $username;

public function __construct($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['test-channel'];
}
```

**Server:**

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
    //
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log("Received");       // gets printed

    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

And lastly, **Client**:

```
 <script>
    var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');

    socket.on('test-channel:UserAddedFriend', function(data) {
       console.log('a');     // nothing logged
       console.log(data);    // nothing logged
   });

</script>
```

---

To add, event handler is not used; but when I use event handle function and and use a die&dump `$event`, it dumps successfully.

```
 public function handle(UserAddedFriend $event)
  {
    dd($event->username . ' added you.');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

`socket.on('test-channel:UserAddedFriend', function(data)`

should be

`socket.on('test-channel:App\\Events\\UserAddedFriend', function(data)`